# Why does McKay not use his personal shield emitter in Season 2, episode 1?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

In one of the first episodes, I believe Season 1, Episode 3, Doctor McKay aquires a device which shields him from various kinds of damage. While he initially fails to turn it off, it becomes clear that he can do it, when he really wants to. The device is visible on his chest in the picture below:

[image: shield glowing on McKay's chest]

In the subsequent episodes there are many occasions, where McKay would have had time and incentive to wear this device. I am specifically thinking of Season 2, episode 1, when he goes to activate the shield with only 2 guards, whining about the dangers, as he sets off. He ends up pointing a gun to Wraiths and being saved by Teyla. But several episodes with Kolya should provide further instances where this device would have been used.

So, why does he not use it?

Comment: Why not buy it and find out? :-) [Stargate Live Auction Preview – Part Three](http://www.gateworld.net/news/2010/09/stargate-live-auction-preview-part-three/)

Comment: @Valorum Thanks a lot. I tried to narrow it down and used the correct term.

Comment: He uses it again, repeatedly. But only once he's worked out how to use it safely. Presumably at this point in the show, he's not 100% certain that he can remove it again; http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Personal_shield_emitter

Comment: @Valorum: That article names _one_ time it was worn again, in a book.

Comment: @lightnessracesinorbit - That particular one, yes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because the personal shield emitter was drained in that episode.
McKay's alternate had one, and Lucius Lavin had one, but that makes 3 overall and if I recall correctly all 3 were drained in the episode that they appeared in. (The alternate McKay we can't be certain of, but it's probable.)

The wiki article says that McKay uses it in a novel. In that case the writer either doesn't pay attention or made up that it recharges over time, which we never see in the show.

Comment: McKay's alternate used it to return to his reality (and, thus, took it with him).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit And presumably it was used up and the energies  were such that it wasn't even sure Alt McKay would survive.

Comment: Is there any mention of it having been drained in the series?

Comment: Rodney's and Lucius'... yes they did. They said what I pointed out about Alt McKay...

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit that was the Alternate McKay's (AKA "Rod") own personal shield, not our Rodney's (that he himself admits he had depleted.)

Comment: @JohnA Yes, I am aware of that.

Comment: @JohnA The parenthetical in the answer suggests an uncertainty as to whether Rod's unit was depleted, but I'm saying it doesn't matter because, even if it hadn't been, our Rodney would not have access to it any more so it not help with the question's premise "Rodney should use a personal shield on an ongoing basis" - even if only two of the observed units are drained, the third is inaccessible.

Answer (score 2):

The battery dies at the end of the episode where he finds​ it. Presumably they either can't be recharged or the Atlantis team never figured out how to recharge them

It's also probable that the devices are somewhat rare, IIRC we only see 2 of the shield devices in the entire run of the show.

Alternate McKay also has one.